# How to show error message when login fails in angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have login page.When user enters wrong password ,server sends error response .How can I show the error message or login fails message in popup.Any Help

//login .ts file

```
onLoginSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    } else {
      const logCredential = {
        username: this.loginForm.get('username').value,
        password: this.loginForm.get('password').value
      };
     this.authServiceObj.onLoginSubmit(logCredential);
 }
```

//html

```
<div class="form-content">
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onLoginSubmit()">
      <h3>LOG IN</h3>
      <div class="form-controls">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Email" type="email" fo    rmControlName="username">
          <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && formControl.username.errors">
            <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.username.errors.required"> * email required</mat-error>

          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div class="form-controls">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput type="password" placeholder="password" formControlName="password">
          <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && formControl.password.errors">
            <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.password.errors.required"> * password required</mat-error>

              </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
         <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Log In</button>
      </div>      
    </form>
  </div>
```

//api call

```
 return this.http.post<User>(apiURL, credentailData,      
 httpOptions).subscribe(
       data => {
         this.setSessionObj(data);
         console.log(data);
         this.router.navigate(['home']);
       },
       error => {
         console.log('Error', error);

       }
     );
```

and also same case with adding details of user .when error is thrown from server.I have to show it in form

Answer (score 0):

Return only below statement from your API call method.

```
  return this.http.post<User>(apiURL, credentailData, httpOptions);
```

And in your login.ts subscribe to HTTP call as follows and handle success and error messages.

```
this.authServiceObj.onLoginSubmit(logCredential).subscribe(data=> {
     this.setSessionObj(data);
     console.log(data);
     this.router.navigate(['home']); 
}, error => {
     // use message in error object
     // you can use Angular Material dialog to show message in the popup.
     // to show message in the form, you can use a class variable and bind it to the template.
});
```